# jQuery element width type

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to use jQuery to figure out the type of width an element has? Whether it's an exact width (like `200px`) or a relative width (such as `20%`).

I would also like to be able to detect if the element doesn't have any kind of width specifically set, either in the CSS file or inline styles.

How would I go about doing this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: This is an interesting question.  How will you use the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value returned by `.css('width')` to get the applied rule. To determine if the style is inline, you'll <s>need to use `.prop('style')` and get a-parsin'</s> use (non-jQuery) `.style.width` (see [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style)).

In general, it is non-trivial to determine whether any given element style comes from explicitly set CSS, or implicitly computed style rules.

Comment: I know I can use `.css('width')` to get the width, but how do I determine if it's a percentage or not?

As for detecting non-computed values, I found this; http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830517/951402 -- would that work?